# Passing Props (NOT FROM URL) with vue-router to a component - VUEJS3

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I am trying to pass props (not params from URL) to a component by using vue-router, as I have researched it was possible with vuejs2 but haven't found solutions for vuejs3 and vue-router

Comment: What did you try and what worked in V2 but not 3? The router is generally designed this way. If you need to make some data to be available in a route, you can do this through global store

Comment: @EstusFlask we were able to pass "props" without adding to the router path "/:param", but now it is not possible, and I havent found a way to pass data to a component (at least not without changing the URL)

Comment: I think you might need to add `props: true` to your route. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same issue in Vue3.